# How to create directory with a certain size?

Tags: fedora, directory, size

How can I create a directory with a certain size?

I need an *empty directory* with atleast 15MiB, and it must be in the `/tmp` directory.

My assignment sounds like that:

> You're supposed to create empty directory in a file system called `/tmp/empty`, which is at least X size.

Comment: The size of directories depends on the filesystem, and how it handles it. You can't change size of the directory, it is not in your competence. Why do you need it?

Comment: I need to do this as a part of uni assignment. #edit: And I'm just curious how to do it. It can be done in ext4 filesystems the way i described it. I can't figure it out for tmpfs.

Comment: @BlueManCZ As a directory is actually 'only' a file 'listing' the entries contained in itself, the size of a directory obviously depends on the amount of entries in it.

Comment: Are you asking about creating a directory with _capacity_ for storing files up to a certain amount?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like what you want is a tmpfs of 15 megs mounted in /tmp...

```
mkdir /path/to/mountpoint
mount -t tmpfs -o size=15M tmpfs /path/to/mountpoint
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of your assignment might be that it is **not** possible to create an **empty** directory, which itself consumes more than 40 bytes, on a tmpfs filesystem.
If you fill that directory with files, the size of the directory will grow with each file and shrink with each deleted file. Therefore it looks like the directory is reorganized with each created/deleted file.
This behavior could possibly be configured with some mount options, but that is beyond my knowledge. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

[Konrad Zagozda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/405810/konrad-zagozda) writes,

Thank you for answers; I figured it out, i needed ext filesystem and its fragmentation. I could mount ext filesystem in `/tmp/empty`